# Using R to find a specific set of rows within a Dataframe bases one a set a variables

Tags: r

I have a large Dataframe consisting of reviews of beer it contains duplicate reviews and some variance within the duplicates.

```
> head( beer_data ) 

  brewery_id            brewery_name review_time review_overall
1      10325         Vecchio Birraio  1234817823            1.5
2      10325         Vecchio Birraio  1235915097            3.0
3      10325         Vecchio Birraio  1235916604            3.0
4      10325         Vecchio Birraio  1234725145            3.0
5       1075 Caldera Brewing Company  1293735206            4.0
6       1075 Caldera Brewing Company  1325524659            3.0
  review_aroma review_appearance review_profilename
1          2.0               2.5            stcules
2          2.5               3.0            stcules
3          2.5               3.0            stcules
4          3.0               3.5            stcules
5          4.5               4.0     johnmichaelsen
6          3.5               3.5            oline73
                      beer_style review_palate review_taste
1                     Hefeweizen           1.5          1.5
2             English Strong Ale           3.0          3.0
3         Foreign / Export Stout           3.0          3.0
4                German Pilsener           2.5          3.0
5 American Double / Imperial IPA           4.0          4.5
6           Herbed / Spiced Beer           3.0          3.5
               beer_name beer_abv beer_beerid
1           Sausa Weizen      5.0       47986
2               Red Moon      6.2       48213
3 Black Horse Black Beer      6.5       48215
4             Sausa Pils      5.0       47969
5          Cauldron DIPA      7.7       64883
6    Caldera Ginger Beer      4.7       52159
>
```

I would like to use ddply to summarize the duplicate beers review columns into a new smaller dataframe for analysis is this possible using ddply?

Comment: You say you want to summarize. But how? You can calculate the mean, median, sd, sum, ...

Comment: an average of the review stats for example there might be 3 reviews of cauldron DIPA with 3 different ratings on taste i would like to combine those 3 reviews while taking a mean of the taste review ect.

Comment: @Dr.Eloyd - It seems to me you need to take a step back and get more familiar with `R` before using a complex package like `plyr`. For example, you should first learn basic operations like subsetting `[`

Comment: Thankyou alex im trying to learn the basics on a very short time table ! Thankyou for pointing out subsetting it looks promising. Any other important functions i might find useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
duplicate_data <- ddply(beer_data, .(brewery_id), function(x) {
    if(nrow(x) > 1)
        return(data.frame("brewery_id" = unique(x$brewery_id), "mean_ratings" = mean(x$review_overall)))
        # You can fill in the rest
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Maisaura !I'm fairly new to R how could i do the means of the individual ratings?

Comment: Updated the answer. You can fill in the rest for the other ratings.

Comment: Thankyou again Maisaura ill put it to good use :)

Comment: Hey maiasaura ive incorporated some sqldf into my code but when running your script i've come up with an error i edited my original question .

Comment: Error in data.frame(breweryname = unique(x$breweryname), meanratings = mean(x$reviewoverall),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 5, 3